# line height on mac and windows different

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, google-chrome

heloo, 
i just include font on my project. its looks good on chrome with os windows, but when i check on mac with safari browser. font is on line top. so i check again on mac with google chrome, the font is still on line top. but when i check to windows pc its looks great

here the picture of chrome on windows

[image]

heres on safari and chrome with mac 
[image]

css is simple:

```
.initiative_buttons_title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 56px;
    font-size: 4rem;
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 62px;
    background: #00b1f0;
    font-family: Langdon,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

what happen guys.

Comment: Check computed values. They may be different as you're using `rem`s.

Comment: how to check that

Comment: Check your screenshots. On the right-side of both the dev tools you can see a tab named "computed". The property should be listed along with its computed value.

Comment: they have same properties. i dont know why its different. i need lineheight 72px on mac alone. any suggest?

Comment: So are they different values?

Comment: no, nodifferent values

Comment: I have the same issue right now and my conclusion so far is that it's a font-issue, not a property value issue.